# Is it possible to make typescript-ref DTO generator to respect nullable properties?

Tags: c#, typescript, servicestack

I am trying to achieve valid DTO generation using `typescript-ref` utility from ServiceStack. Problem is: for nullable and reference properties it will not generate the default value definition.

There is C# definition of a DTO:

```cs
public class Data
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public int? OptionalValue { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Generated typescript DTO will look like this:

```js
export class Data
{
    public value: number;
    public optionalValue: number;
    public text: string;

    public constructor(init?: Partial<Data>) { (Object as any).assign(this, init); }
}
```

This will lead to static checking problems. You will not be able to set `undefined` or `null` value (whatever will be selected to represent C# `null` value) to those properties. Because of `Partial` constructor it is possible to just omit them, but still it isn't convenient.

Also TypeScript compiler will not know that those fields can have undefined value - this is where we will lose static checking for those DTOs completely.

I found `MakePropertiesOptional: True` [documented option](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/TypeScript-Add-ServiceStack-Reference#makepropertiesoptional) that will make every property in generated DTOs optional. But this not solving my problem but leads to more of them. Is there any more flexible ways to solve it?

I need to have generated DTO for above class to look like this:

```js
export class Data
{
    public value: number;
    public optionalValue?: number;
    public text?: string;

    public constructor(init?: Partial<Data>) { (Object as any).assign(this, init); }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've improved support for this in the latest [ServiceStack v5.8.1 pre-relase now on MyGet](https://docs.servicestack.net/myget).

The default implementation should now generate optional TypeScript properties for Nullable properties. So by default it will now generate:

```
export class Data
{
    public value: number;
    public optionalValue?: number;
    public text: string;

    public constructor(init?: Partial<Data>) { (Object as any).assign(this, init); }
}
```

To just have specific properties required and all other properties optional you can enable the `MakePropertiesOptional: True` option then mark which properties should be required with the `[Required]` attribute, e.g:

```
public class Data
{
    [Required]
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public int? OptionalValue { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

This will generate your desired:

```
export class Data
{
    // @Required()
    public value: number;

    public optionalValue?: number;
    public text?: string;

    public constructor(init?: Partial<Data>) { (Object as any).assign(this, init); }
}
```

Another option to make all **reference** and **nullable** properties optional and value types required is using the new `IsPropertyOptional` filter, e.g:

```
TypeScriptGenerator.IsPropertyOptional = (generator, type, prop) => 
    prop.IsValueType != true || prop.Type == typeof(Nullable<>).Name;
```

Or with the new `PropertyTypeFilter` you could instead make every property nullable, e.g:

```
TypeScriptGenerator.IsPropertyOptional = (generator, type, prop) => false;

TypeScriptGenerator.PropertyTypeFilter = (gen, type, prop) => 
    gen.GetPropertyType(prop, out var isNullable) + "|null";
```

Which is now what gets configured you set:

```
TypeScriptGenerator.UseNullableProperties = true;
```

Which will generate every property as nullable, e.g:

```
export class Data
{
    public value: number|null;
    public optionalValue: number|null;
    public text: string|null;

    public constructor(init?: Partial<Data>) { (Object as any).assign(this, init); }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, `IsPropertyOptional` solved my problem. Just to extend this answer a litte: `TypeScriptGenerator` is a class from `ServiceStack` package that defined in `ServiceStack.NativeTypes.TypeScript` namespace. It responsible to setup metadata generated by web service that will be used to generate DTOs.

Comment: can we make `JsConfig.IncludeNullValues = true;` to serialize to `undefined` instead of `null`?
Or can we setup to generate `| null` union type instead of optional properties with `TypeScriptGenerator.IsPropertyOptional`?

Comment: @PavelMikheev Apart from being a breaking change, emitting `undefined` instead of the expected `null` would be contradictory and unintuitive and result in serializing invalid JSON that would break all standard JSON serializers. I've added a PropertyTypeFilter in [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/132262cbae5dc5a34cdcdf3cfb29fe95da8169ce) similar to IsPropertyOptional which you can choose to change the property type per property. Will be on MyGet later today.

Comment: @PavelMikheev The `PropertyTypeFilter` is now [available on MyGet](https://docs.servicestack.net/myget#redownloading-myget-packages), note that both Property filters [now take the TypeScriptGenerator](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/b0306d8f32e92954ab5d2e17ee047ffdcbaa97d4) instead of the Config (available at generator.Config) which you'll need if you need any of the instance generator APIs.

Comment: Thank you. Can you provide an example of how to achieve `null` instead of `undefined` for optional properties using `PropertyTypeFilter`? I was unable to figure it out myself.

Comment: @PavelMikheev Some properties & APIs needed to made public in [latest v5.8.1 on MyGet](https://docs.servicestack.net/myget#redownloading-myget-packages), then see my updated answer for an example for how to make every property nullable.